# What is a VM transport in the context of an ESB?

Tags: virtual-machine, terminology, esb

I'm reading the [Mule ESB](http://www.mulesoft.org) documentation, and there is a lot of references to VM Queues. Is this some sort of JMS implementation? What is meant by it, and where can I find more info?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Mule specific transport for messaging within the same VM (i.e. the mule standalone server or the tomcat instance mule has been deployed to). The transport can implement queuing with in-memory or on-disk storage, but there aren't any reliability guarantees.

See here:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE2USER/VM+Transport

[http://mulesux.tumblr.com/post/3102264921/murphys-law-or-dropping-the-ball](http://mulesux.tumblr.com/post/3281881692/vm-queues-set-up-for-failure)

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that.  Everything I've read just assumes you know what it means. From the second link, I take it you are not a Mule fan?

Comment: Lol - not really! I shamelessly plugged my own blog.

Answer (score 1):

I've never worked with Mule, but I read some docs a few years ago.

I believe VM queues would reside in memory within the JVM.  I think it's a way to use SOA constructs between Java Beans, so that local POJO methods can be treated as services.  That way, if you some day want to replace that POJO with an external service or host it elsewhere, you only have to change the configuration of that service.

This is all conjecture from the small amount of Mule I recall, so definitely verify, verify, verify.  :-)

Comment: Seems reasonable. Of course when you search for Java + VM or just VM Queues in general you are headed off in the wrong direction. At least it seems that way. I'll give this a few days to see if anyone else answers then mark it as accepted if no one else adds anything more viable. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I searched for `mule "vm:"` and found these which both seem helpful: http://ricston.com/blog/?p=83 and http://oss.org.cn/ossdocs/soa/mule/1.3/Vm%20Provider.html